# How to redirect std::cout and printf in windows

Tags: c++, windows

i have created program based on this article [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28VS.85%29.aspx), but it doesn't work std::cout and printf, so from program like this i got ony "Hello, momma" string and nothing came from cout and printf parts:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    const char *buffer = "Hello, momma";

    std::cout << buffer << " - iostream version\n";

    printf("%s - stdio version", buffer);

    DWORD dwWritten = 0;
    WriteFile(hStdOut, buffer, strlen(buffer), &dwWritten, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

**Q:** How can i intercept cout and printf? **I have no access** to source code of child program, i just need to intercept its output.

---

This is the output if run only child process:

> Hello, momma - iostream version
>
> Hello, momma - stdio versionHello, momma

so, as you can see, all three versions are printed.

---

As requested code of parent program:

```
void RedirectIO(HANDLE &hRead, HANDLE &hWrite)
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES attr;
    ZeroMemory(&attr, sizeof(attr));
    attr.nLength = sizeof(attr);
    attr.bInheritHandle = true;

    CreatePipe(&hRead, &hWrite, &attr, 0);
    SetHandleInformation(hRead, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
}

bool CreateChild(std::string CommandLine, DWORD WaitTime, HANDLE hInRead, HANDLE hOutWrite)
{
    STARTUPINFO SI;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION PI;
    ZeroMemory(&SI, sizeof(SI));
    ZeroMemory(&PI, sizeof(PI));

    SI.cb = sizeof(SI);
    SI.hStdError = hOutWrite;
    SI.hStdInput = hInRead;
    SI.hStdOutput = hOutWrite;
    SI.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    bool success = CreateProcess(0, const_cast<char*>(CommandLine.c_str()), 0, 0, true, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NO_WINDOW, 0, 0, &SI,&PI);

    if (success)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(PI.hProcess, WaitTime);
        CloseHandle(PI.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(PI.hThread);
    }

    return success;
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE hRead = nullptr;
    HANDLE hWrite = nullptr;

    RedirectIO(hRead, hWrite);
    CreateChild("stdouterrin.exe", INFINITE, nullptr, hWrite);

    DWORD ReadCount = 0;
    char Buffer[1024] = {0};

    std::string data = std::string();

    while(true)
    {
        if (!ReadFile(hRead, Buffer, sizeof(Buffer) / sizeof(char), &ReadCount, 0))
            break;

        if (!ReadCount) break;

        Buffer[ReadCount] = '\0';
        data.append(&Buffer[0], ReadCount);
        std::cout<<"Read From Child:\n\n"<<data.c_str()<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: don't use strlen, it is dangerous. WriteFile could have called it, and not insisted that you pass in the length, but it knows better.

Comment: Finding it difficult to understand your results, can you paste the output in a panel below the code.

Comment: Could be that you need to call `fflush(stdout)`, can't tell though until I see the output.

Comment: @richard what's the problem with `strlen()`? Of course `WriteFile()` doesn't use it because the input buffer to `WriteFile` isn't necessarily a null terminated string. Instead `WriteFile()` relies on the caller to know how to calculate the right length, and in this case `strlen()` is the correct method.

Comment: @bames53 yes as you say as long as you don't mess up, and pass a string that has a null in the middle you will be ok. But programmer mess up, that is where the bugs come from. So better to be cautious.

Comment: I think you should show your actual code in the parent process that's redirecting the standard output, not just the code for the child process.

Comment: That output looks correct. What where you expecting?

Comment: @richard if that were the case, then the issue would show up several lines before the usage of `strlen`, namely when writing to `cout`. As far as I know, the `iostream` overloads don't check bounds for a `char*` argument when sending output, they just send characters until they get to `\0`, so your buffer would be truncated anyway. And if you're dealing with a block of binary data, you wouldn't be using `strlen` to find the length to begin with. Of course, given that this is C++, I'd prefer using `std::string` over C-style strings anyway.

Comment: Yes yes yes in this case `strlen` is safe. It is not the problem, just a warning. The same as when I dropped an axe and it missed my foot my ½ an inch. It was perfectly safe, because it missed. Now has anyone worked out what the question is?

Comment: @richard Should have just used a saw.

Comment: @richard He's using a string literal which necessarily produces a string with the correct terminating null. Hardcoding the length would be more error prone than `strlen()`. As long as he's using `char *` then `strlen()` is the best option. Perhaps you're suggesting that `std::string` be used instead, in which case I'm generally on board with that.

Comment: Try to add `fflush(stdout); // stdout is the standard FILE* output stream` after the `printf` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flush the buffers.

i.e.

```
cout << flush;
fflush(stdout);
```

before the `return 0;`

Comment: i have no access to the source code of a child program, but i do need to intercept its output.

Comment: @Yola As a separate program, or linked to your code? In the fist case look up `popen()`.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ it is windows

Comment: That's not answering his question, how does your code talk to the child?  And how did you print the child program's code if you don't have access to it, or is the code above just to recreate the problem?